# Zend Routing / URL helper . Have a global parameter show up first in URL

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, zend-route, zend-view, zend-router

Was curious if anyone knew the best way to implement the following: I have a parameter in my zend framework 1.12 app which effectively controls the 'scope' of things, and is a field in every table in my db to represent the scope of a row.  It is a simple integer variable, and can be thought of as 'buildingID', so it controls which 'building' we are working with.

In a plugin, I have:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->setGlobalParam('building', DYNAMIC_INT);
```

which accomplishes what I need. When I build a URL with the URL view-helper I have my parameter, but it is always at the end of the parameter list.  I know this is trivial from a programming perspective, but how would I achieve 'prepending' this global param to my url parameters?

```
site.com/admin/controller/action/param1/xyz/param2/xyz/building/2
```

to become

```
site.com/admin/controller/action/building/2/param1/xyz/param2/xyz ?
```

Open to any ideas.  If you want me to overload the url view helper, can you provide some example code, because I had trouble setting up this class.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [custom route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html) to accomplish this. Setup the route somewhere in your bootstrap file:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':controller/:action/building/:building/*'
);
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
$router->addRoute('building', $route);
```

And then, assuming that the following has been called at some point prior to using the url view helper...

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->setGlobalParam('building', DYNAMIC_INT);
```

...you can specify the route as the second argument of the helper:

```
echo $this->url(array(
    'controller' => 'admin',
    'action' => 'controller',
    'param1' => 'xyz',
    'param2' => 'xyz',
), 'building');

// /admin/controller/building/1/param1/xyz/param2/xyz
```

Comment: works beautifully.  Thanks for the tip...Very clear to me now what needs to be done